# ActiveMQ Ubuntu server admin console

Tags: ubuntu, activemq-classic

I installed the activeMQ package from ubuntu repositories and it's properly set up and running on my ubuntu-server VM. The problem is that I cannot connect to the admin console.
I noticed that on windows bin the jetty.xml is imported on the activemq.xml so I did also in the ubunut-server. But still nothing. Can someone point out what else has to be done ?

EDIT
After suggetions I should have posted the config, so here it is.

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
      http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data"
        destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">

  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
          <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
            <vmCursor/>
          </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
        </policyEntry>
        <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

  <destinations>
    <queue physicalName="CMAgentStatus"/>
    <queue physicalName="CMUpdateRequest"/>
    <queue physicalName="CMSnapshotEvent"/>
  </destinations>

  <managementContext>
    <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
  </managementContext>

  <persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
  </persistenceAdapter>

  <transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
  </transportConnectors>

</broker>

<!--    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>  -->
</beans>
```

When I include the jetty.xml the activeMQ doesn't load. No messages on the activemq.log though.

The jetty.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="securityLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
  <property name="name" value="ActiveMQRealm"/>
  <property name="config" value="${activemq.base}/conf/jetty-realm.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.security.Constraint">
  <property name="name" value="BASIC"/>
  <property name="roles" value="admin"/>
  <property name="authenticate" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
  <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint"/>
  <property name="pathSpec" value="/*"/>
</bean>
<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
  <property name="loginService" ref="securityLoginService"/>
  <property name="authenticator">
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator"/>
  </property>
  <property name="constraintMappings">
    <list>
      <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping"/>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="handler">
    <bean id="sec" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
      <property name="handlers">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <property name="contextPath" value="/admin"/>
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin"/>
            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true"/>
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

            <property name="contextPath" value="/camel"/>
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/camel"/>
            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true"/>
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <property name="contextPath" value="/demo"/>
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/demo"/>
            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true"/>
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <property name="contextPath" value="/fileserver"/>
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/fileserver"/>
            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true"/>
            <property name="parentLoaderPriority" value="true"/>
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
            <property name="directoriesListed" value="false"/>
            <property name="welcomeFiles">
              <list>
                <value>index.html</value>
              </list>
            </property>
            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/"/>
          </bean>
          <bean id="defaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
            <property name="serveIcon" value="false"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
</bean>

<bean id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start"
      destroy-method="stop">

  <property name="connectors">
    <list>
      <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>

  <property name="handler">
    <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
      <property name="handlers">
        <list>
          <ref bean="contexts"/>
          <ref bean="securityHandler"/>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>

</bean>

</beans>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should post your config along with any related errors you are getting, not really enough info here to make a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that the ports that are configured are available and allowed by whatever security policy you have in place.  If Jetty can't bind to 8161 then you will have an issue.

Comment: I think I am missing the webapps folder in the linux tar binary. I tried add this to the `/usr/share/activemq` folder and restart activemq. Log is clean but activemq doesn't load.